# Error in library(functional) : there is no package called ‘functional’ - While running MR using rmr2

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, revolution-r

I am trying to run a simple MR program using rmr2 in a single node Hadoop cluster. Here is the environment for the setup

Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit)
R (Ubuntu comes with 2.14.1, so updated to 3.0.2)
Installed the latest rmr2 and rhdfs from [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Downloads) and the corresponding dependencies
Hadoop 1.2.1

Now I am trying to run a simple MR program as

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/training/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/training/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop")

library(rmr2)  
library(rhdfs)

ints = to.dfs(1:100)  
calc = mapreduce(input = ints, map = function(k, v) cbind(v, 2*v))
from.dfs(calc)
```

The mapreduce job fails with the below error message in **hadoop-1.2.1/logs/userlogs/job_201310091055_0001/attempt_201310091055_0001_m_000000_0/stderr**

```
Error in library(functional) : there is no package called ‘functional’  
Execution halted  
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1  
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)  
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
```

But, the `sessionInfo()` shows that functional package has been loaded

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

>locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

>attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

>other attached packages:
 [1] rhdfs_1.0.6    rJava_0.9-4    rmr2_2.3.0     reshape2_1.2.2 plyr_1.8      
 [6] stringr_0.6.2  **functional_0.4** digest_0.6.3   bitops_1.0-6   RJSONIO_1.0-3 
[11] Rcpp_0.10.5
```

**Update** : I am able to run a R MR job reading and writing from STDIO without using the rmr2 and the rhdfs libraries as mentioned [here](https://coderwall.com/p/imxf6g). So, for now my guess is that the problem is isolated to rmr2 and the rhdfs packages.

How to get around this problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade R and install all the packages as `sudo ...` (as root)? Perhaps you are having a user vs system context issue. The environment seen by the R script running in hadoop may not be the same as a that from a user's interactive R command line, which appears to be where you are running `sessionInfo()`. Can you run `sessionInfo()` from within the script?

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I have installed R using the `sudo apt-get ...` command and upgraded the R packages into a private library. I am able to run MR programs (Java and Streaming) and simple R programs successfully using `vm4learning` user. The users are same for both of them, so there seems to be no context issue. The problem is running R MR programs using rmr package as `vm4learning` user.

Answer (score 5):

Install the dependencies for rmr2/rhdfs in a system directory instead of a custom directory (~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0). This can be done running R as sudo and then installing the dependencies. Thanks to [Antonio](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rhadoop/_8B7kQVPXGM) for the help in the RHadoop forums.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread. I am also stuck at the similar problem. I have only one node in cluster, where R packages are getting installed in ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2. Can you please guide me how to change package directory?

Comment: I got it worked finally. Thanks for putting up the fix.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution of these kind of problem is re-installation since in sesssionInfo()
you are getting

```
**functional_0.4**
```

while when i did sessionInfo() i got

```
functional_0.4
```

i guess there is some missing dependencies you might be missing so use from your R console

```
install.packages("functional",dependencies="TRUE")
```

to fix any problem due to any other packages .

P.S: Choose cloud-0 mirror from the available ones.

If still that does not help i recommend you use r-base-dev as your R version though i don't have a reason to justify this using http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Thanks

Comment: Did try the mentioned solutions already and none of them worked. r-base has a dependency on r-base-dev, so it is already installed. Already reinstalled it a couple of times.